# Workflow Task without action/outcome

Tags: 2013, workflow, tasks

I would like to create and assign a task item to a person within a workflow. But the person should not be forced to enter any data or accept the task or anything else. 
The task should only be an information that they should do something.

Then the workflow waits for an update of a field on some items and finishes when the items are completed (Wait for Field Change in Current Item - WF action).

How can I achieve a task that gets created by the workflow, where user has nothing to do and the workflow continues without an interruption?

FYI: Running 2010 WF engine on 2013 SP environoment

Answer (score 1):

Just send the user an email then wait for change in field, any sort of task or collect data action is going to create a task for the user to do something. There is no task that can be created without an outcome.

If you need to make a record of it, you could create a list to log that information. So the logic then would be Create a informational record in your list, email user, wait for change.

Comment: I agree with Eric. A task requires an action. If there is no action for the user to take, creating a task is useless. Just sending the user an email will inform them about something they should do.

Comment: Creating a task is not uselesse, because with emails you can lose the overview quiet fast. I need a list for the user where he can filter the tasks that are assigned to him, to give him an overview which one are finished and which not.

Comment: Then that is a task with an outcome, they have to do something as you mentioned.